# trying to insert into DB from URL but doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, url, pdo, get-request

I am trying to insert into DB getting data from URL but doesn't work

here the link
http://localhost/test/recevier.php?heat1=33&heat2=33&heat3=33&gas=33&motion=33

here my db.php  file

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test;";
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';

try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'field to connect' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

and here my recevier.php file

```
include "db.php";

$heat1 = $_GET['heat1'];
$heat2 = $_GET['heat2'];
$heat3 = $_GET['heat3'];
$gas = $_GET['gas'];
$motion = $_GET['motion'];
$personId = 1;
echo $heat1;
echo $heat2;
echo $heat3;
echo $gas;
echo $motion;
$entryId = 3;

$vars = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO var(entryId, heat1, heat2, heat3, gas, mation, personId) VALUES (:zentryId, :zheat1, :zheat2, :zheat3, :zgas, :zmotion, :zpersonId)");

$vars->bindParam(':zentryId', $entryId);
$vars->bindParam(':zheat1', $heat1);
$vars->bindParam(':zheat2', $heat2);
$vars->bindParam(':zheat3', $heat3);
$vars->bindParam(':zgas', $gas);
$vars->bindParam(':zmotion', $motion);
$vars->bindParam(':zpersonId', $personId);

$vars->execute();
```

and this is the table I am trying to insert into

the 'echo' statement to check if the file get the data & he git it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVnX2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the error says? Anyway I notice there's a typo in this line:

```
$vars = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO var(entryId, heat1, heat2, heat3, gas, mation,
```

Should it be :

```
$vars = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO var(entryId, heat1, heat2, heat3, gas, motion, personId) VALUES (:zentryId, :zheat1, :zheat2, :zheat3, :zgas, :zmotion, :zpersonId)");
```

Comment: thank you 
i cant believe i didn't notice that